# MATLAB - Global optimization toolbox

Tags: matlab, genetic

When I run the GA solver, I got the following warning: What does it mean? What action should I take or I just ignore it?

Warning: Length of upper bounds is > length(x); ignoring extra bounds.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have specified more upperbounds ub(i) than the number of unknown variables, nvars. The extra ub(i) will be ignored by GA.